# After webpack(Nextjs 10 project) changes tailwind errors

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, webpack-4

Before the changes, everything was going to build and everything worked.

my next.config.js //

```
// const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css');
// const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');

class TailwindExtractor {
  static extract(content) {
    return content.match(/[A-Za-z0-9-_:\/]+/g) || [];
  }
}
const nextConfig = {
   ...
};

module.exports = withPlugins([
   // [ withSass, {} ],
   // [ withCss, {} ],
   [ withPurgeCss, {
      ...
   }
], nextConfig);
```

Further, as recommended, I decided to abandon the use of the deprecated @ zeit / next-css and @ zeit / next-sass

I added the tailwind.config.js file as written on their website:

```
module.exports = {
purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
theme: {
    extend: {},
},
variants: {
    extend: {},
},
plugins: [],
};
```

And made changes to post.config.js and also installed the missing packages:

```
module.exports = {
plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
    'postcss-preset-env': { stage: 2 },
},
};
```

In _app.js, I include the main.scss file:

```
@import "tailwindcss/preflight";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

.self-class {
    @apply .bg-olive .shadow-olive .text-base .text-white .font-bold;
}
```

**I get an error:** `Error: Syntax error: /home/roma/project/main.scss` @apply`cannot be used with`.bg-olive`because`.bg-olive`either cannot be found, or its actual definition includes a pseudo-selector like :hover, :active, etc. If you're sure that`.bg-olive`exists, make sure that any`@import`statements are being properly processed *before* Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as`@apply `can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.`

Do I have my tailwind.config.js file configured incorrectly or is the file built incorrectly in general? So where I am trying to refer to tailwind styles is not known about them yet?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You don't have to put a dot in `@apply` syntax. Do it like this `@apply bg-olive shadow-olive;` Also follow [color customizing guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#customizing) to add `olive` color to your palette. Also consider enabling `jit` mode, and remove purge CSS from config. Moreover, there is no need of `postcss-import` if you are using SASS/SCSS. And instead of importing tailwind styles, you can just use the `@tailwind` directive. Please refer the official documentations and examples. Currently the question has too much problems.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it.